# Use cases where multiple saml assertions are needed in a single saml response?

Tags: saml

From http://saml.xml.org/assertions, 
" Note that a SAML response could contain multiple assertions, although its more typical to have a single assertion within a response."

But I want to know some practical scenarios where multiple assertions are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assertions are claims made by the Identity Provider (IdP). An `Attribute` is contained in an `AttributeStatement`, so email address, first name, surname etc would be `Attribute` instances in an `AttributeStatement` contained in a single `Assertion`. Each `Assertion` needs a `Subject` and can be used for different things. Normally there is only one `Assertion` containing an `AuthenticationStatement` and an `AttributeStatement` containing `Attribute` instances.

One use case for multiple `Assertion` could be a claim about the `Subject` that is time limited differently from the `Attribute` list. e.g. perhaps some fact about the user that should only be relied on for a short period of time, defined by `Conditions`->`NotBefore`->`NotOnOrAfter`. Perhaps some authentication mechanism that only allows users to be authenticated at the IdP for a short period of time, compared to the longer period of time their `Attribute` list can be used for.

You can see a use case for multiple `Assertion` in a `SAMLResponse` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592636/is-it-valid-to-have-more-than-1-samlassertions-in-a-saml-token-response).